# Outlook 2013 rule or script to automatically set follow-up for the last day of the month?

Tags: email, script, rules

Every month I receive an e-mail somewhere around the 15th. I would like to create a rule that automatically sets a follow-up reminder for the 30th of the month. I don't see any way to do that with any of the rule options.

I thought creating a custom script to set a reminder date for the end of the month would be a solution, but I don't know what attributes I would set for that.

Information and suggestions would make me finitely happy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'task scheduler' in the operating system.

Create a trigger.  This can be time based and has options for last day of the month.
Create an action.  The option to send an email is available.  You will use your smtp server as the outbound server, this could be the IP address of your internal exchange server if you have one and your administrator allows outbound SMTP.

You can also supply a path to an automatically updated file to use as an attachment.

Outlook does not have an automatic feature to schedule an outbound email with a time based trigger.

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is to automatically set a reminder for the end of the month on an **incoming** e-mail message that arrives in the middle of the month. I can do it manually, but I was hoping to automate the process.